# How to remove all pictures from the Photos app and put them in a folder?

Tags: macos, mac, photos

I want to store some pictures that I had in a camera in a folder on my mac, but when I inserted its memory card on the the respective USB port, the app `Photos` opened up, and there was the option to import the pictures, which is what I did.

Now, I just would like to retrieve all these pictures and put them in a folder that I want. How can I do it? I don't want this Photos app to keep track of any picture that I imported actually.

Answer (score 2):

By default, imported original photos are located at:

> ~/Pictures/Photos Library.photoslibrary/Masters/

So putting them into a folder is as simple as copying the 'Masters" folder elsewhere.

Alternatively you can select the photos you wish to retrieve and then go to `File > Export > Export Unmodified Original`.